Clang LLVM not generating .section in the output code for i686 target on windows
I am working with clang llvm and trying to have the pragma defines in my output code. The .section is not getting in the output of the code. I am trying to generate the output for the below test.c code.
#include <stddef.h> // test.c file

#pragma clang section bss="myBSS" data="myData" rodata="myRodata" relro="myRelro" text=".myText"

int var1;
int var2;
int var3 = 7;
const int var4 = 10;

void notmain(void);

void notmain(void) {}

int main(void) 
{
    notmain();
}

I cross-complile using clang llvm using the following command for i686 target.
$ clang --target=i686-pc-windows-msvc -S -o test_s.s test.c

I get the below output in the assembly
    .text
    .def    @feat.00;
    .scl    3;
    .type   0;
    .endef
    .globl  @feat.00
.set @feat.00, 1
    .file   "test.c"
    .def    _notmain;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    ,"xr"
    .globl  _notmain                        # -- Begin function notmain
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_notmain:                               # @notmain
# %bb.0:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    popl    %ebp
    retl
                                        # -- End function
    .def    _main;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .globl  _main                           # -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main:                                  # @main
# %bb.0:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    calll   _notmain
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popl    %ebp
    retl
                                        # -- End function
    .globl  _var3                           # @var3
    .p2align    2, 0x90
_var3:
    .long   7                               # 0x7

    .globl  _var4                           # @var4
    .p2align    2, 0x90
_var4:
    .long   10                              # 0xa

    .globl  _var1                           # @var1
    .p2align    2, 0x90
_var1:
    .long   0                               # 0x0

    .globl  _var2                           # @var2
    .p2align    2, 0x90
_var2:
    .long   0                               # 0x0

    .addrsig
    .addrsig_sym _notmain

why is it missing the pragma clang .section for the variables?
This doesn't happend when I use the target as i686-pc-linux-gnu. The output for this is as below?
.text
    .file   "test.c"
    .section    .myText,"ax",@progbits
    .globl  notmain                         # -- Begin function notmain
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   notmain,@function
notmain:                                # @notmain
    .cfi_startproc
# %bb.0:
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset %ebp, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %ebp
    popl    %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa %esp, 4
    retl
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   notmain, .Lfunc_end0-notmain
    .cfi_endproc
                                        # -- End function
    .globl  main                            # -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# %bb.0:
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset %ebp, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %ebp
    pushl   %ebx
    pushl   %eax
    .cfi_offset %ebx, -12
    calll   .L1$pb
.L1$pb:
    popl    %ebx
.Ltmp0:
    addl    $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+(.Ltmp0-.L1$pb), %ebx
    calll   notmain
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addl    $4, %esp
    popl    %ebx
    popl    %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa %esp, 4
    retl
.Lfunc_end1:
    .size   main, .Lfunc_end1-main
    .cfi_endproc
                                        # -- End function
    .type   var3,@object                    # @var3
    .section    myData,"aw",@progbits
    .globl  var3
    .p2align    2, 0x0
var3:
    .long   7                               # 0x7
    .size   var3, 4

    .type   var4,@object                    # @var4
    .section    myRodata,"a",@progbits
    .globl  var4
    .p2align    2, 0x0
var4:
    .long   10                              # 0xa
    .size   var4, 4

    .type   var1,@object                    # @var1
    .section    myBSS,"aw",@nobits
    .globl  var1
    .p2align    2, 0x0
var1:
    .long   0                               # 0x0
    .size   var1, 4

    .type   var2,@object                    # @var2
    .globl  var2
    .p2align    2, 0x0
var2:
    .long   0                               # 0x0
    .size   var2, 4

    .ident  "clang version 18.1.8"
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
    .addrsig
    .addrsig_sym notmain

Can someone support me in figuring out why this happens?

The clang docs say that:

This feature is only defined to work sensibly for ELF and Mach-O targets.

So I belive this pragma is simply ignored.
